# MISSING_GROUP_BY The query does not include a GROUP BY clause - pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by

I am getting the below error when I try to select specific columns from a dataframe.The error is coming from `.withColumn("action",self.get_action(self))`. If I remove that call I can get the rest of the columns without the error.

> [MISSING_GROUP_BY] The query does not include a GROUP BY clause. Add GROUP BY or turn it into the window functions using OVER clauses.;

If I add a group by `.groupby(cols)`  with the cols list then I still get the error.I don't think I am using `collect_set` the right way.

```
cols = ["my_key","id","active","dt_start_end","action"]
 
 return (df
           .withColumn("my_key", lit(f"{my_key}"))
           .withColumn("id", lit(f"{id}"))
           .withColumn("active", lit(True))
           .withColumn("dt_start_end", self.get_start_end(self))
           .withColumn("action",self.get_action(self))
           .select(*cols)
           .distinct()    
         )

def get_start_end(self):
    
    return struct(
        to_timestamp(col("dt_start")).alias("start")
        ,to_timestamp(col("dt_end")).alias("end")
    )

def get_action(self):
    
    return collect_set(
        struct(
            lit("source_key).alias("key")
            ,col("action").alias("value")
            ,col("benefit").alias("benefit")
            ,col("text").alias("text")
        )
    )
```

Comment: Please add some sample inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, collect_set is used over multiple *rows*, meaning you have to group the rows using a groupby or a window. From your code, it looks like you want to collect multiple *columns* in one column. For this, you could use f.concat, f.array, or f.array_distinct. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, to_timestamp, collect_set, struct, col

cols = ["my_key", "id", "active", "dt_start_end", "action"]

return (df
    .withColumn("my_key", lit(f"{my_key}"))
    .withColumn("id", lit(f"{id}"))
    .withColumn("active", lit(True))
    .withColumn("dt_start_end", self.get_start_end(self))
    .withColumn("action", self.get_action(self))
    .groupBy(*cols)  # Group by the columns you want to distinct by
    .agg(
        collect_set(
            struct(
                lit("source_key").alias("key"),
                col("action").alias("value"),
                col("text").alias("text")
            )
        ).alias("action")  # Apply collect_set as an aggregation function
    )
)
```